# sqlite error con datos nulos

Tags: c#, sqlite

Alguien me puede decir porque no puedo actualizar datos si la condición del update contiene valores (Null), esta es la consulta:

```
UPDATE Buff_Table SET EsNulo='0' WHERE  ValidityTime=(Null);
```

En cambio si hago al revés si funciona, ejemplo:

```
UPDATE Buff_Table SET EsNulo=(Null) WHERE  ValidityTime='0';
```

desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En SQL cuando quieres evaluar si un valor es nulo o no, debes utilizar el operador `IS NULL`.

De esta forma tu condición quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE Buff_Table SET EsNulo='0' WHERE  ValidityTime IS NULL;
```

Tu segundo ejemplo funciona porque efectivamente le puedes asignar `NULL` a cualquier campo que lo admita.

En la [documentación](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-is-null/) del operador `IS NULL` se puede leer algo parecido a las siguientes afirmaciones:

> `NULL` es especial. Indica que una información es desconocida o no aplicable.

> `NULL` no es igual a nada, ni siquiera al número cero, una cadena vacía, etc.
>
> Especialmente, el `NULL` no es igual a sí mismo.

También afirman que el resultado de condicionales del estilo `ValidityTime = NULL;` siempre será 0 (o falso) incluso comparar `NULL = NULL` también será 0 (o falso)